# Product image import

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have an Excel file with SKU, product name, and image. Then there’s another row with the same SKU and the same product name as the first row, but the image name changes, so it becomes another image for the product. Is it possible to import images in this format into WordPress using a plugin?

I have WP All Import, but it requires images to be on the same row and separated by commas.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.